# C# ContainsKey does not find Key in dictionary alltough it is present

Tags: c#, system.type

**EDIT: This is no longer about GetHashCode!**

I'm implementing a game with Unity/C# and have a dictionary of effects where the key is the System.Type of the effect and the value is a list of effects registered for that type.

When I want to query effects from the dictionary the ContainsKey method does not find any keys after my dictionary got deserialized by some Json.Net logic. (works in other cases). However, the dictionary does contain types with correct hashcodes.

```cs
public bool GetEffects<T>(out List<T> queriedEffects) where T : Effect
{
  queriedEffects = null;
  int test = typeof(T).GetHashCode();
  foreach(Type t in activePersistantEffects.keys)
  {

     if (t.GetHashCode() == test)
     { Debug.Log("Hashcode is working"); } //Prints to log correctly

     if (t == typeof(T))
     { Debug.Log("== is working"); } //Does not print to log

     if (t.Equals(typeof(T)))
     { Debug.Log(".Equals() is working"); } //Does not print to log
  }
  if (activePersistantEffects.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) //Returns false
  {
      queriedEffects = activePersistantEffects.GetEffects<T>();
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Since the hash code is equal for the concrete instances in the KeyCollection I thought this must work?

Any thoughts suggestions? Would really like to solve this without having to rework a bunch of the codebase^^ Thanks in advance guys!

Edit: After trying to debug via the FullName attribute I am even more puzzled. The types seem to be equivalent:
[image: Method returns false even tough FullNames of types are equivalent.]

Comment: If two values are equal, they must have the same hash code. But the reverse is not true (and indeed, in most cases cannot be true, because we have more possible values than there are possible hash codes). The results you demonstrate are consistent with this: the types are not actually equal, although they happen to have the same hash code. Now as to *why* that's the case, that needs more investigating. For example, check the `FullName` of your types.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't Dictionary.ContainsKey use hash codes? But yes, I will check FullName thank you!

Comment: Because hash codes are not unique, a dictionary cannot use them as a substitute for comparison -- it will first look up the bucket of the key according to the hash code, *then* compare the keys for equality just in case two different values happened to have the same hash code. Under normal circumstances, the hash codes for two different values would be different, but a dictionary cannot assume this and remain correct. Indeed, a dictionary behaves correctly (if very slowly, because it degrades to a list) if all the keys had the exact same hash code.

Comment: I cannot really reproduce your problem. Can you give a an example of a minimal filled dictionary and a call to `GetEffects` that fails?

Comment: Okay I tried to debug using FullName as @JeroenMostert suggested. This seems to imply that there is infact a correct key in the dictionary.

Comment: Okay. Using TryGetValue instead of ContainsKey solves the issue allthough I have no idea why...